# Find first record of multiple values in single query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

**Table**

```
            timestamp             | tracker_id | position 
----------------------------------+------------+----------
 2020-02-01 21:53:45.571429+05:30 |         15 |        1
 2020-02-01 21:53:45.857143+05:30 |         11 |        1
 2020-02-01 21:53:46.428571+05:30 |         15 |        1
 2020-02-01 21:53:46.714286+05:30 |         11 |        2
 2020-02-01 21:53:54.714288+05:30 |         15 |        2
 2020-02-01 21:53:55+05:30        |         12 |        1
 2020-02-01 21:53:55.285714+05:30 |         11 |        1
 2020-02-01 21:53:55.571429+05:30 |         15 |        3
 2020-02-01 21:53:55.857143+05:30 |         13 |        1
 2020-02-01 21:53:56.428571+05:30 |         11 |        1
 2020-02-01 21:53:56.714286+05:30 |         15 |        1
 2020-02-01 21:53:57+05:30        |         13 |        2
 2020-02-01 21:53:58.142857+05:30 |         12 |        2
 2020-02-01 21:53:58.428571+05:30 |         20 |        1
```

**Output**

```
           timestamp             | tracker_id | position 
----------------------------------+------------+----------
2020-02-01 21:53:45.571429+05:30 |         15 |        1
2020-02-01 21:53:45.857143+05:30 |         11 |        1
2020-02-01 21:53:55+05:30        |         12 |        1
```

How do I find the first record `WHERE tracker_id IN ('15', '11', '12')` in a single query?

I can find the first record by separately querying for each `tracker_id`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE tracker_id = '15'
ORDER BY timestamp
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Is there any primary key in that table?

Comment: @Andronicus There's no primary key constraint, but `timestamp` will be unique

Comment: @saintlyzero check my query, optimized and perfectly working below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres this can be done using the `DISTINCT ON ()` clause:

```
select distinct on (tracker_id) *
from the_table
where tracker_id in (11,12,15)
order by tracker_id, "timestamp" desc;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bd0d18e231b5b0b3c3f020ad9feb00e4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first_value` with the nested `select` query:

```
select mt.*
from my_table mt
where mt.timestamp in (
    select first_value(imt.timestamp) over (partition by imt.tracker_id order by imt.timestamp)
    from my_table imt
    where imt.tracker_id in ('11', '12', '15')
)
```

I'm assuming `timestamp` is unique, like you said in the comment. You can always replace the joining column with a primary key, like `id`.

Answer (score 1):

I have named your timestampl column col1 because I do nto recommend to name your columns with keywords.

```
select * from mytable m
where m.col1 = (select min(col1)
              from mytable m1
              where m.tracker_id = m1.tracker_id
              group by tracker_id)
and m.tracker_id in (11,15,12);
```

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=44c8aef9401d7a4c87e90d5d884cb3ee)

Answer (score 1):

Find this Query:

You can uncomment where clause if you want to run query for selected tracker_id

```
   ;WITH CTE AS
   (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tracker_id ORDER BY timestamp) 
      duplicates, * FROM my_table -- WHERE tracker_id IN (15,11,12)
   )
   SELECT timestamp, tracker_id, position FROM CTE WHERE duplicates = 1
```

Comment: Before marking as kindly run the query and see the result it is tested query

Comment: It's probably because of `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["` (and Postgres needs the statement termination character `;` at the end of a statement, not the beginning)

Comment: Hey @a_horse_with_no_name it's was only spelling mistake, kindly re run it, and it is for all tracker id, if you want selected tracker_id you can pass it in where clause.

Comment: This is still invalid (standard SQL) and won't run on Postgres

Comment: It's perfectly working on postgress as well, square bracket give the error at postgress, so I have removed the sqaure bracket

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct on (tracker_id) *
from the_table
where tracker_id in ( select distinct tracker_id from the_table)
order by tracker_id, "timestamp" desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first row that matches each of your `IN` values, you can use a window function:

```sql
SELECT src.timestamp, src.tracker_id, src.position
FROM (
  SELECT 
    t.timestamp, t.tracker_id, t.position, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tracker_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) myrownum
  FROM mytable t
  WHERE tracker_id IN ('15', '11', '12')
) src
WHERE myrownum = 1 -- Get first row for each "tracker_id" grouping
```

This will return the first row that matches for each of your `IN` values, ordering by `timestamp`.